# C# создание многоуровневого словаря

Tags: c#, словари

**Задача**

Переписываю свой код из Lua на C#. На примере с адресами местожительства будет проще продемонстрировать.

Нужно прочитать инфу из текстового файла и сохранить во многомерном массиве, чтобы получать доступ к инфе на каждом из его уровней. Выбор пал на Dictionary, поскольку имеет схожую механику с таблицами в Lua, плюс дополнительные ништяки.

Мне необходимо, чтобы в приведенном ниже коде я мог выполнить строку 4 без ошибок. Как правильно инициализировать словарь в таком случае?

**Ожидание**

```
//г. Москва, ул. Мясницкая, д. 3, кв. 2
object City = "Москва";
object Street = "Мясницкая";
object House = 3;
object Apartment = 2;

//варианты инициализации словаря
var map = new Dictionary<object, object>(); // 1
//var map = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>(); // 2
//var map = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>>(); // 3
//var map = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>>>(); // 4

//строки с ошибками компилятора
map[City] = new Dictionary<object, object>(); // 1
map[City][Street] = new Dictionary<object, object>(); // 2
map[City][Street][House] = new Dictionary<object, object>(); // 3
map[City][Street][House][Apartment] = true; // 4
```

**Результат**

- При 1м варианте компилятор ругается на строки 2, 3 и 4.
- При 2м варианте на строки 3 и 4.
- При 3м варианте на строки 1 и 4.
- При 4м варианте на строки 1 и 2.

Во 2м варианте еще более-менее начинает работать, поскольку я уже могу что-то записать в двумерный словарь

```
map[City][Street] = true;
```

Но мне требуется создать четырехмерный (а возможно и еще крупнее).

---

---

---

**Рабочий код на основе моего вопроса и ответов пользователей**

```
object City = "Москва";
object Street = "Мясницкая";
object House = 3;
object Apartment = 2;

var map = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>>>();

map[City] = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>>();
map[City][Street] = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<object, object>>();
map[City][Street][House] = new Dictionary<object, object>();

map[City][Street][House][Apartment] = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это хоть и работает, но в C# так не принято писать.

```
string City = "Москва";
string Street = "Мясницкая";
int House = 3;
int Apartment = 2;

var map = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>>>();

map[City] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>>();
map[City][Street] = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>();
map[City][Street][House] = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

map[City][Street][House][Apartment] = true;
```

Я задал явно типы `string`, `int`, `bool`. При желании можно вернуть `object`.

Comment: Вижу в чем была ошибка. На каждом уровне надо было инициализировать внутренние словари. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно, но добавление какое-то очень длинное получается.

Answer (score 1):

Создаёшь класс-наследник `Map<K, V>` словаря, явно указываешь, что имплементируешь интерфейс `IDictionary<K, V>`. Для ключа указываешь констрейнт `new()`.

Оператор квадратных скобок не виртуальный, поэтому перегружать придётся через new, соответственно класс можно будет использовать либо по его имени, либо по явному интерфейсу. При приведении к Dictionary фича потеряется.

В перегруженном операторе `[]` делаешь `TryGetValue` и если не получилось достать, то добавляешь новый объект в словарь.

Теперь будет работать так без лишних созданий:

```
var map = new Map<string, Map<string, Map<int, Map<int, bool>>>>();
map[City][Street][House][Apartment] = true;
```